# Google Analytics V2 SDK for Android crashing older platform devices

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have started testing Google Analytics on my app, however I notice it crashes my app on startup for older devices. How can I resolve this?

Works on platform 4.2 , API level 17... Testing on target 2.3.5 the app crashes and does not start.

Code snippet:

```
//Code from my Main Activity…..
private GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance().startNewSession("UA-329229164-1", 25, this);
  mWebView.loadUrl("www.mysite.com");
  //store loaded URL page
  String current = mWebView.getUrl();
  //track the page and visit
  this.tracker.trackPageView(current);
}

protected void onDestory()
{
  super.onDetachedFromWindow();
  tracker.stopSession();
}
```

**Error:**

```
12-10 01:49:32.615: W/Ads(24918): **No Google Analytics: Library Incompatible.**
12-10 01:49:32.745: D/Database(24918): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.media.trips/databases/webview.db, flag = 6, file size = 29696
12-10 01:49:32.755: D/Database(24918): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.medi.trip/databases/webview.db, mode: delete, disk free size: 34 M, handle: 0x275840
12-10 01:49:32.775: D/Database(24918): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.media.trips/databases/webviewCache.db, flag = 6, file size = 23552
12-10 01:49:32.775: D/Database(24918): dbopen(): path =
```

Comment: What is MainPage's line 128?

Comment: this.tracker.trackPageView(current);...128

Comment: String current = mWebView.getUrl();

Comment: thanks , newbie question but why would my app be working for some devices and not others?

Comment: Most likely webView's implementation changed between platforms. However I am really not sure at the moment. You should post your full code so people other than me may help!

Comment: oh ok, just pasted my code there, thanks over much

Comment: I decided to implement flurry instead it's a lot easier and well my app didn't crash thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem, sorry I couldn't figure it out. Can't get every always get everything. Keep your question open though, maybe someone *other* than me has input that will help others.